# rdiscount Ruby gem fail to install

Tags: linux, ruby

## My system

- OS: openSUSE Leap 42.1
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 3.16.7-29-desktop
- Shell: zsh 5.0.5
- CPU: Intel Core i7-3610QM CPU @ 3.3GHz

`gem -v` : `2.2.2`

## What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to install Nesta CMS but one of the runtimes dependencies fail to install : [rdiscount](https://rubygems.org/gems/rdiscount).

Normal Output as root :

```
 % gem install rdiscount                                                                                                                                                                              ~ linux-7o7a
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rdiscount:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby.ruby2.1 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib64/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rdiscount-2.1.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/rdiscount-2.1.8/gem_make.out
```

Debug output as root (quite long):
[debug link](http://hastebin.com/bixajonesi.vhdl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to install the ruby developper package `ruby-devel` :

```
% zypper install ruby-devel                                                                                                                                                                                                     ~ linux-7o7a
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following 2 NEW packages are going to be installed:
  ruby-devel ruby2.1-devel

2 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 3.1 MiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the operation, additional 20.1 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/? shows all options] (y): y
Retrieving package ruby2.1-devel-2.1.2-5.7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                        (1/2),   3.1 MiB ( 20.1 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: ruby2.1-devel-2.1.2-5.7.x86_64.rpm ...........................................................................................................................................................................[done (595.5 KiB/s)]
Retrieving package ruby-devel-2.1-3.2.x86_64                                                                                                                                                             (2/2),  10.5 KiB (   84   B unpacked)
Retrieving: ruby-devel-2.1-3.2.x86_64.rpm ..............................................................................................................................................................................................[done]
Checking for file conflicts: ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................[done]
(1/2) Installing: ruby2.1-devel-2.1.2-5.7 ..............................................................................................................................................................................................[done]
(2/2) Installing: ruby-devel-2.1-3.2 ...................................................................................................................................................................................................[done]
```

After that, `rdiscount` installed well :

```
% gem install rdiscount                                                                                                                                                                                                         ~ linux-7o7a
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rdiscount-2.1.8
Parsing documentation for rdiscount-2.1.8
Installing ri documentation for rdiscount-2.1.8
Done installing documentation for rdiscount after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```